# Facebook share button, displaying old description text but a new image

Tags: php, facebook

I implemented the facebook share button on my web page, but it displays an old description text, I need to have a new text related to every article that I share, the image is updated as new.
Here is the link it's in arabic: http://achabakamagazine.com/new/articles.php?f=1&issueID=320&categoryID=26&articleID=9675&page=4

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you follow [Facebook sharing standards](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices).

After that go to [Facebook Url Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and check your each url stats.